# How do I eliminate the views/scripts folder?

Tags: php, zend-framework, view

Let's say I'm tired of having to put my page template folders under views/scripts and want to just put them under views, leaving out the "scripts" part of the path. How can I alter the config of ZendFramework to permit me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

// ...

    protected function _initView()
    {
        // Initialise the view
        $view = new Zend_View();
        $view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views');

        // set the configured view as the view to be used by the view renderer.
        $renderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
        $renderer->setView($view);

        return $view;
    }

// ...

}
```

The previous answer is missing the part where you set the view you have configured to have the additional script path to the View Renderer.

HTH.

Comment: My fault. I assumed he knew how to do this part.

Answer (score 1):

See [ZF Manual for `Zend_View`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.controllers.html#zend.view.controllers.script-paths) and place this in your bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initView()
    {
        $view = new Zend_View();
        $view->setScriptPath('/some/new/path');   // overwrite any paths
        $view->addScriptPath('/some/other/path'); // adds additional paths
        $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv(
            'Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
        );
        $viewRenderer =
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
            'ViewRenderer'
        );
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
        return $view;
    }
}
```

or [configure your Ini for use with `Zend_Application_Resource_View`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.view)

```
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/scripts"
...
```

Note that the selected basePath assumes a directory structure of:

```
base/path/
    helpers/
    filters/
    scripts/
```

See also this [tutorial by Padraic Brady](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/standardise.the.bootstrap.class.with.zend.application).

Comment: Is there anyway to do this globally on a project so that I don't need to keep adding this in each class method of a controller?

Comment: Yes. See my addition for placing it into the Ini

Comment: I set your INI suggestion to "/views" instead of "/views/scripts", and then tried in the configs/application.ini under "production". It didn't work and errors out looking for "scripts".

Comment: Edit your question to include some of your bootstrap code then. Can't tell without seeing.

Comment: I just used quickstart. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Both options I gave you do work. If you want to set the basePath via ini, you have to use the default directory structure. If you don't want that structure, either use your own Resource_View or use initView as given above.